# Rails3 mysql2 rake error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rubygems

i'm running ruby 1.8.7 with rails3. after installing mysql2 (successful) I want to create the dbs, but the following error occurs:

```
noname:addressDB clemens$ rake db:create
(in /.../addressDB)
rake aborted!
undefined method `errno' for #<Mysql2::Error:0x1024f21f0>

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
noname:addressDB clemens$
```

any advice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed I was having similar issues on my databases (not this error exactly). It was due to an incorrect version of MySQL. I had to downgrade to MySQL 5.1 and the errors went away.